# one of two parameters mandatory

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a solid PowerShell function with parameters.
Now the problem is I don't get the ParameterSetNames to work.

What I want to get is that

1. computername OR ipaddress is always mandatory
2. computername or ipaddress has to be set but not both at the same time (If possible )
3. if adminuser or adminpassword are given the other one is mandatory

I tried a lot of diffrent settings but keeps failing
this was my last attempt

```
CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="IpAddress")]  
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(
     # computername: Name of the host you want to connect to.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerName", Position=0)]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="IpAddress")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameCredentials", Position=0)]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="IpAddressCredentials")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="IpAddressUser")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameUser", Position=0)]
     [String]$computername,

     # ipAddress: Ip Address of the host you want to connect to.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ComputerName")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddress", Position=0)]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameCredentials")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressCredentials", Position=0)]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressUser", Position=0)]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameUser")]
     [switch]
     [String]$ipAddress,

     # credentials: PowerShell credentials use to connect to the host.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ComputerName")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="IpAddress")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameCredentials")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressCredentials")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="IpAddressUser")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameUser")]
     [PSCredential]$credentials,

     # adminUser: Username to use to connect to the host.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ComputerName")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="IpAddress")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameCredentials")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="IpAddressCredentials")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressUser")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameUser")]
     [String]$adminUser,

     # adminPassword: Password to use to connect to the host.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ComputerName")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="IpAddress")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameCredentials")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="IpAddressCredentials")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressUser")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameUser")]
     [String]$adminPassword
)
```

Comment: "not both at the same time (If possible )" is not possible using parameter rules only. your code should check if both are set and either ignore one (possibly with a warning) or throw and exception.

Comment: Why would you need computername OR IP to be a separate parameter?  You could ask for "computer" and they could put either name or IP and then use that as the target.  I'm curious why you'd specifically need 2 distinct parameters for that one.

Comment: @longneck, it is indeed possible, and advisable over testing and throwing exceptions. See my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hm, I think you have too many parameter sets. Also not sure why you have separate user/password parameters and a PSCredential parameter. You should really just use the PSCredential. But I'll assume you need this for some reason (please consider changing it).

4 parameter sets:

1. ComputerNameCred
2. ComputerNamePlain
3. IpAddressCred
4. IpAddressPlain

```powershell
function Thing {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="ComputerNameCred")]  
    Param
    (
         # computername: Name of the host you want to connect to.
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameCred", Position=0)]
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNamePlain", Position=0)]
         [String]$computername,

         # ipAddress: Ip Address of the host you want to connect to.
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressCred", Position=0)]
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressPlain", Position=0)]
         [String]$ipAddress,

         # credentials: PowerShell credentials use to connect to the host.
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameCred")]
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressCred")]
         [PSCredential]$credentials,

         # adminUser: Username to use to connect to the host.
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressPlain")]
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNamePlain")]
         [String]$adminUser,

         # adminPassword: Password to use to connect to the host.
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressPlain")]
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNamePlain")]
         [String]$adminPassword
    )
}

Get-Help Thing # use this to make sure your parameter sets are as they should be.
```

I also removed `[switch]` from your IP address parameter; not sure why that was there. You may want to consider using `[System.Net.IPAddress]` for that parameter instead of `[String]`. It will still accept strings (they will be cast), but it automatically validates the parameter since the cast will fail if it's not a valid IP.

Comment: this is almost what I wanted and helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

this is my solution
thanks to briantist

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="ComputerName")]  
Param
(
     # computername: Name of the host you want to connect to.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameCred", Position=0)]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNamePlain", Position=0)]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerName", Position=0)]
     [String]$computername,
     # ipAddress: Ip Address of the host you want to connect to.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressCred", Position=0)]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressPlain", Position=0)]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddress", Position=0)]
     [String]$ipAddress,

     # credentials: PowerShell credentials use to connect to the host.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNameCred")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressCred")]
     [PSCredential]$credentials,

     # adminUser: Username to use to connect to the host.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressPlain")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNamePlain")]
     [String]$adminUser,

     # adminPassword: Password to use to connect to the host.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="IpAddressPlain")]
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="ComputerNamePlain")]
     [String]$adminPassword,

     # writeLog: Boolean that enables or disables log-writing.
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
     [Boolean]$writeLog=$true
)
```